# python script gets stuck on keylogger listner

Tags: python, keylogger

the keylogger is getting stuck on listening for keys i tried putting the listening part in another script but it wasnt practical, is it possible to utilise threading for this?

```
log_dir = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + 'keylogs.txt'), \
    level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as lister:
    lister.join()

path = r'C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop\keylogger\keylogs.txt'
f = open((path), 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
file = f.readlines()
```

Comment: you have to put code before `listener.join()`. BTW: listener already use `thread` to run it and you don't need other thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something when `Listener` is running then you have to do before `.join()` because it waits for end of listener.

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as lister:

    # ... your code ...

    lister.join()
```

`Listener` already uses `threading` to run code so you don't have to run it in `Thread` and you can write it in similar way to `threading`

```
lister = Listener(on_press=on_press)  # create thread
lister.start()                        # start thread
  
# ... your code ...

lister.join()                         # wait for end of thread
```

---

**BTW:**

It has also all other functions from normal `Thread` - ie. `lister.is_alive()` to check if `Listener` is still running.

In opposite to normal `Thread` it has also command `lister.stop()` to stop this `Listener`